# Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments junit:junit:4.12

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just updated my android studio and created fresh project but im getting this error now:

```
ERROR: Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Here my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blurbnow.emirhan.heartkeeper_test2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Im searching it but i couldn't find any solution. Would be glad if someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though not a complete answer to your question I found a way to get around this problem: 
go to *Project Structure > Project >* and change 
 
**Gradle Version: 4.6** 
**Android Plugin Version: 3.2.1** 
according to table given here: 
 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle 
Edit: It didn't work on first try but after I changed I's into İ it worked. Kudos to Mehmet Erdogdu!

```
testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

or some country have this problem
another option may be this help you

in Gradle Scripts>build.gradle (app: Module)

```
testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestİmplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

change it `testImplementation` --> `testİmplementation` (replace the I with İ)

Answer (score 0):

//testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

commented these lines
then click button "make project"(ctrl + F9)
finally click "try again"
this solution worked for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have update your Studio 3.3.0 you are seeing this error.
Did you write your project with include Kotlin lang
Check your lang version.

File>Settings>Plugins> and search Kotlin. 
Now check version from right panel

after that go to Gradle Scripts>build.gradle
check version
if it is not same. change it. like me

**//ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'**

**ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'**

i fix that error.

--Mehmet

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. First of all im using java not kotlin. But when i try to create a  kotlin project, i got same error. Even i applied same steps

Answer (score 0):

Just for another option, setting the system language as English then creating a fresh project works for me.